# How to ouput desired data from a key in JSON if there are multiple keys

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I want to output data of the lyrics_body key from the following URL.[API Link](https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/matcher.lyrics.get?callback=format=jsonp&q_track=O%20Saathi&q_artist=Arijit%20Singh&apikey=c12b7dffb9a86d5b6d70e0f0fdeab589)

But the JSON text on that URL is like that following.

```
{
 "message": {
    "header": {
          "status_code": 200,
          "execute_time": 0.0047609806060791
     },
    "body": {
       "lyrics": {
          "lyrics_id": 16894378,
          "can_edit": 0,
          "locked": 0,
          "published_status": 8,
          "action_requested": "",
          "verified": 0,
          "restricted": 0,
          "instrumental": 0,
          "explicit": 1,
          "lyrics_body": "Kis Tarah Main Bataoon\nKee Adhura Main Hoon\nYah 
          Yakeen Dilaoon\nBana Tere Lie Hee Main Hoon\nMamam. Ab Yah Hee Hai 
          Meree Khvaahish\nIs Pal Ko Toh Main Jee Loon\n\nTu Iss Jagah Hai 
          Khada\nPhir Bhi Hai Door Tu Haan\nKuch Na Raha Darmiyaan\nPhir Kyun 
          Dil Keh Raha\n\nO Saathi…Itna Toh Bas Kar De\n...\n\n******* This 
          Lyrics is NOT for Commercial use *******",
          "lyrics_language": "",
          "lyrics_language_description": "",
          "lyrics_copyright": "Lyrics powered by www.musixmatch.com. This Lyrics 
          is NOT for Commercial use and only 30% of the lyrics are returned.",
          "writer_list": [],
          "publisher_list": [],
          "backlink_url": "https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Arijit-Singh/O-
          Saathi?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=",
          "updated_time": "2017-07-26T07:05:50Z"
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Now how can I output text from only `lyrics_body` key to a div element which has `id="result"`.I have tried many methods but no outputs.

Comment: try this: body.lyrics.lyrics_body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    
 $( "#target" ).click(function() {
  var url = 'https://crossorigin.me/https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/matcher.lyrics.get?callback=format=jsonp&q_track=O%20Saathi&q_artist=Arijit%20Singh&apikey=c12b7dffb9a86d5b6d70e0f0fdeab589'
$.getJSON(url, function(result) {
    console.log(result.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body)
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  Click here
</div>
<div id='data'></div>
```

Comment: All codes are working here in snippet sir.But when I coded them in notepad in a html file nothin appears.My code: https://pastebin.com/cZhNFR0N

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">  ... </script>

Comment: Data will show your console , I have check again its working

Answer (score 2):

Access nested `json` keys via dot notation: `json.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body`.

Use `.innerText` to append text to the element. Use `.getElementById("")` to find an element by its `id` attribute.

```js
var json = {
     "message": {
        "header": {
              "status_code": 200,
              "execute_time": 0.0047609806060791
         },
        "body": {
           "lyrics": {
              "lyrics_id": 16894378,
              "can_edit": 0,
              "locked": 0,
              "published_status": 8,
              "action_requested": "",
              "verified": 0,
              "restricted": 0,
              "instrumental": 0,
              "explicit": 1,
              "lyrics_body": "Kis Tarah Main Bataoon\nKee Adhura Main Hoon\nYah Yakeen Dilaoon\nBana Tere Lie Hee Main Hoon\nMamam. Ab Yah Hee Hai Meree Khvaahish\nIs Pal Ko Toh Main Jee Loon\n\nTu Iss Jagah Hai Khada\nPhir Bhi Hai Door Tu Haan\nKuch Na Raha Darmiyaan\nPhir Kyun Dil Keh Raha\n\nO Saathi…Itna Toh Bas Kar De\n...\n\n******* This Lyrics is NOT for Commercial use *******",
              "lyrics_language": "",
              "lyrics_language_description": "",
              "lyrics_copyright": "Lyrics powered by www.musixmatch.com. This Lyrics is NOT for Commercial use and only 30% of the lyrics are returned.",
              "writer_list": [],
              "publisher_list": [],
              "backlink_url": "https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Arijit-Singh/O-Saathi?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=",
              "updated_time": "2017-07-26T07:05:50Z"
            }
         }
       }
    }
document.getElementById("result").innerText = json.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Everyone's code is working here!But when i coded them in a html file inside the <script>tag my browser shows nothing why?

Comment: Paste the entire HTML file with `<script>` tags to your question, then I'll help you answering this.

Comment: No need Sir.I have got my solution.Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Right, sure. If my answer was helpful, an upvote would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

Get JSON via .getJSON. After parse set #result to `data.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body`

```js
var url = 'https://crossorigin.me/https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/matcher.lyrics.get?callback=format=jsonp&q_track=O%20Saathi&q_artist=Arijit%20Singh&apikey=c12b7dffb9a86d5b6d70e0f0fdeab589'
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $('#result').text(data.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">#Result</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to store those data into a variable.

```
var myData = {
    //your json data
}
```

then `console.log(myData.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body)` see if you are getting the right value.